# JavaFX - MaterialDesignIcons / GluonHQ Icon not showing

Tags: java, javafx, gluon-desktop, material-design-icons

One of my coworkers created a mock-up of a JavaFX GUI using Netbeans. I am now in charge of turning it into a first prototype of the app. I imported the generated Java and FXML files in my Eclipse, but when I try to run it it fails to display the button icons.

The icons are declared in the FXML file as follows:

```
<?import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.Icon?>

<Icon content="FILE_DOWNLOAD" prefHeight="112.0" prefWidth="119.0" />
```

But the result when I run it is just an empty rectangles: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ODfh.jpg

I tried to add a Maven dependency to MaterialDesignIcons (which apparently what Gluon uses to get the icons), but it didn't change anything. I also tried to run Maven in debug mode, but I don't see any warning or error related to this issue.

Comment: `Icon` class belongs to Gluon Mobile library (which is commercial, btw), and its css is enabled only if your application class extends from `MobileApplication`, which is intended for mobile apps (though it can run on desktop as well).

Comment: I would suggest trying https://kordamp.org/ikonli/.

Answer (score 0):

Use FontAwesomeFX

They have a library for MaterialDesign and Material Icons as well...

https://bitbucket.org/Jerady/fontawesomefx

https://bintray.com/jerady/maven/FontAwesomeFX/view